# Sort tuple ListBuffer

Tags: list, scala, listbuffer

So i have this `ListBuffer` with 2 values: `String` and `BigDecimal`, after populate my `List` i want to sort it before print:

```
var data = new ListBuffer[(String, BigDecimal)]
data+=(("se", 34))
data+=(("sh", 4))
data+=(("fjd", 33))
data+=(("dhdh", 24))
data+=(("dhd", 125))
```

And i wonder how to sort this according `BigDecimal` value so this is what i have try:

```
val list = data.map(x=>x._2 > x._2)
```

Comment: `map` is the wrong method to use, it does not sort anything; it transforms elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sortBy` and use the ordering of the value of the second element as following,

```
data = data.sortBy(_._2)
```